# How to get current row inserted

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table, and in it I have
`UsernameID`,`UniqueID`, `component`, `coorX`, `coorY`, `coorX2`, `coorY2`.
The `UniqueID` is created by Auto Increment. I want to get the current row after I insert into my table. How do I insert the current row in MySQL? I'm using Java.

In php they used

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

Can you give me an example of a script to insert the current row in MySQL using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JDBC standard feature, see Statement.executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys),  example:

```
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into t1 (UsernameID) values (1)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    long id = rs.getLong(1);
```

Comment: sir i got error when i try your script this is my script when i add your command http://pastebin.com/jeLiq8eR

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use PreparedStatement  for the same.

String ColumnsArray[] = {"columnName"};
String sqlQuery = " " // write your insert query here
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,ColumnsArray);
pstmt.setString(1, "anyvalue");

pstmt.execute();
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rs.next())
long key = rs.getLong(1);
```